# RSA coding java

Tags: java

coding encryption and decryption of my image was successful but an error appeared when I want to decrypt the encryption image that added noise.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:349)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
at RSA.map(RSA.java:198)
at RSA.decryptImage(RSA.java:93)
```

My RSA coding is

```
   public static BufferedImage map(
        BufferedImage image,
        boolean encrypt,
        String keyPath) throws Exception{

    RSA rsa = new RSA();

    int wScale = 4; 
    int hScale = 2;

    if(image.getWidth() % 2 != 0 || image.getHeight() % 2 != 0){
        throw(new Exception("not even"));
    }


    int newWidth = (encrypt) ? image.getWidth() * wScale : image.getWidth() / wScale;
    int newHeight = (encrypt) ? image.getHeight() * hScale : image.getHeight() / hScale;

    BufferedImage encImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

    if (encrypt) {

        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x += 2) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y += 2) {
                int counter = 0;
                int length = 16;
                byte[] pixelBytes = new byte[length];

                // Rolling 4 pixel menjadi array 1d
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                        int val = image.getRGB(x + i, y + j);

                        val += x * y;

                        byte[] sub = intToByteArray(val);

                        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) pixelBytes[(counter) * 4 + k] = sub[k];
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                PrivateKey privateKey = rsa.getPrivate(keyPath);
                rsa.cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

                byte[] enc = rsa.cipher.doFinal(pixelBytes);

                counter = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                        byte[] sub = new byte[4];
                        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                            sub[k] = enc[(counter) * 4 + k];
                        }

                        int val = byteArrayToInt(sub);

                        encImage.setRGB((x * wScale) + i, (y * hScale) + j, val);

                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("encrypt done");
    } else {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth() / wScale; x += 2) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight() / hScale; y += 2) {

                int counter = 0;
                int length = 128;
                byte[] pixelBytes = new byte[length];

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        int val = image.getRGB((x * wScale) + i, (y * hScale) + j);

                        byte[] sub = intToByteArray(val);

                        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) pixelBytes[(counter) * 4 + k] = sub[k];
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                PublicKey publicKey = rsa.getPublic(keyPath);
                rsa.cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

                byte[] enc = rsa.cipher.doFinal(pixelBytes);

                counter = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

                        byte[] sub = new byte[4];
                        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                            sub[k] = enc[(counter) * 4 + k];
                        }

                        int val = byteArrayToInt(sub);
                        val -= x * y;

                        encImage.setRGB(x + i, y + j, val);

                        counter++;
                    }
                }

    return encImage;
}
```

this coding wa successfull but if i add noise in encryption image and i want to decrpyt that image will error. help me to fix this coding pls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: To clarify: are you adding the noise before encryption or after encryption?

Comment: i but noise after encryption sir

Comment: Once noise has been added to an encrypted value, it cannot be decrypted back to its original value unless you can work out how to remove that noise.

Comment: i know that cannot be decrypted back to original. can fix this error and just show again image with noise if cannot decrypt sir?

Comment: That is also impossible.